# How to run gui apps like gvim from docker container

Tags: docker, user-interface

To play around with a docker image, I installed docker and ran a sample docker ubuntu image as follows. (I hope I am using terminology correctly, still a docker noob)

`docker run -it ubuntu`

Because gvim or anyother gui based program was not installed, by default, I did, inside the ubuntu docker container

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install x11-apps vim-gtk
```

However, on running xclock I get

```
root@59be2b1afca0:/# xclock
Error: Can't open display: :0
root@59be2b1afca0:/#
```

On running gvim I get

```
root@59be2b1afca0:/# gvim
E233: cannot open display
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So why won't gui apps work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers weren't quite designed originally for gui apps, but rather for services, workers, processes, etc.. On the other hand since containerisation is a kernel construct to isolate and dedicate resources in a more managed way which can expose ports or share volumes, and devices etc..

This means you can technically map your screen, audio, webcam devices to a container by using `--device /dev/xyz` when you run your `docker run` command:

```
docker run [--rm [-it]|-d] \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
-e DISPLAY \
--device /dev/dri \
myimage [cmd]
```

I actually found an article describing this here - including audio, camera and other device mapping.

- http://somatorio.org/en/post/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thanks! But it does not seem to work for me, yet. Possibly there is an error with the way I am running your suggested command.  I tried running  `docker run -it -v  /tmp/.X11-unix/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY --device /dev/dri ubuntu` after having commited an image which contained the installation of xclock and vim-gtk. On running xclock I still get `Error: Can't open display: :0`